# Wireless network/nodes

Tags: pstricks

I am actually using LatexDraw for my graphs. I would like to know if there is any package that provides wireless network components such as : base station, nodes, terminal, wireless signal, ...

I am trying to reproduce the image in Fig.2 : [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.07154.pdf)

Thanks.

Here is a piece of code that shows some components (code has been generated by LatexDraw)

```
% \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
% \usepackage{epsfig}
% \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
% \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
% \usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
% \usepackage{etoolbox} % For spaces in paths
% \makeatletter % For spaces in paths
% \patchcmd\Gread@eps{\@inputcheck#1 }{\@inputcheck"#1"\relax}{}{}
% \makeatother
% \psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-3.96)(14.612,3.96)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](7.1101594,0.56974924)(0.19668874,0.09733542)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](6.9134707,0.56639284)(6.782345,-0.111598745)(6.782345,-0.111598745)(6.782345,-0.111598745)(6.782345,-0.111598745)(6.782345,-0.111598745)(6.782345,-0.111598745)(6.782345,-0.111598745)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](7.297805,0.56639284)(7.437974,-0.111598745)
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(2.8,-0.64)
}
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(2.8,-0.64)
}
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(6.782345,-0.09369812)
\lineto(6.855498,-0.14644134)
\curveto(6.892074,-0.17281312)(7.0383797,-0.19391021)(7.1481085,-0.18863587)
\curveto(7.2578373,-0.18336181)(7.3858547,-0.15699035)(7.440719,-0.09369798)
}
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](7.1101594,1.0564263)(0.13112582,0.12978056)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](7.1101594,0.92664576)(7.1101594,0.5373041)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, dimen=outer](7.104,1.152)(0.336,0.12)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, dimen=outer](7.104,1.16)(0.576,0.192)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, dimen=outer](7.0959997,1.144)(0.776,0.272)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, dimen=outer](7.0959997,1.152)(1.08,0.408)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, dimen=outer](7.104,1.136)(1.376,0.504)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](4.527586,-1.0037931)(0.3,0.15)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](4.2413793,-0.9675862)(4.0413795,-2.0537932)(4.0413795,-2.0537932)(4.0413795,-2.0537932)(4.0413795,-2.0537932)(4.0413795,-2.0537932)(4.0413795,-2.0537932)(4.0413795,-2.0537932)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](4.7862067,-0.9675862)(5.027586,-2.0537932)
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(4.027586,-2.0262067)
\lineto(4.1391625,-2.1074877)
\curveto(4.1949506,-2.148128)(4.4181037,-2.1806402)(4.5854683,-2.1725123)
\curveto(4.7528324,-2.1643841)(4.948091,-2.123744)(5.0317736,-2.026207)
}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](4.527586,-0.4537931)(4.527586,-1.0537931)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](3.8275862,-0.2537931)(5.2275863,-0.6537931)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](5.2275863,0.1462069)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](5.2275863,-0.053793103)(5.2275863,-0.6537931)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](4.7586207,0.2737931)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](4.7586207,0.073793106)(4.7586207,-0.5262069)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](3.8275862,0.5462069)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](3.8275862,0.3462069)(3.8275862,-0.2537931)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](4.2517242,0.39103448)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](4.2517242,0.21862069)(4.2517242,-0.3813793)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](7.520918,-2.449561)(0.19668874,0.09733542)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](7.3242292,-2.4529176)(7.1931033,-3.1309092)(7.1931033,-3.1309092)(7.1931033,-3.1309092)(7.1931033,-3.1309092)(7.1931033,-3.1309092)(7.1931033,-3.1309092)(7.1931033,-3.1309092)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](7.708564,-2.4529176)(7.8487325,-3.1309092)
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(7.193104,-3.1130085)
\lineto(7.2662563,-3.165752)
\curveto(7.302832,-3.1921234)(7.449138,-3.2132201)(7.558867,-3.207946)
\curveto(7.6685963,-3.202672)(7.796613,-3.1763)(7.8514776,-3.1130083)
}
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](7.520918,-1.9628841)(0.13112582,0.12978056)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](7.520918,-2.0926645)(7.520918,-2.4820063)
\rput[bl](4.304,-2.552){BS}
\rput[bl](7.28,-3.544){ED}
\rput(7.136,-0.472){LU}
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](12.79816,0.5137492)(0.19668874,0.09733542)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](12.601471,0.51039284)(12.470345,-0.16759874)(12.470345,-0.16759874)(12.470345,-0.16759874)(12.470345,-0.16759874)(12.470345,-0.16759874)(12.470345,-0.16759874)(12.470345,-0.16759874)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](12.985805,0.51039284)(13.125974,-0.16759874)
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(12.470345,-0.14969787)
\lineto(12.543497,-0.20244141)
\curveto(12.580073,-0.22881287)(12.726379,-0.24991028)(12.836108,-0.24463592)
\curveto(12.945837,-0.23936157)(13.073855,-0.2129901)(13.128719,-0.14969797)
}
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](12.79816,1.0004263)(0.13112582,0.12978056)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](12.79816,0.87064576)(12.79816,0.48130408)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](10.215586,-1.0597931)(0.3,0.15)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](9.929379,-1.0235862)(9.72938,-2.1097932)(9.72938,-2.1097932)(9.72938,-2.1097932)(9.72938,-2.1097932)(9.72938,-2.1097932)(9.72938,-2.1097932)(9.72938,-2.1097932)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](10.474207,-1.0235862)(10.715587,-2.1097932)
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(9.715586,-2.082207)
\lineto(9.827163,-2.1634874)
\curveto(9.882951,-2.2041285)(10.106104,-2.2366407)(10.273468,-2.228512)
\curveto(10.440832,-2.220384)(10.636091,-2.1797438)(10.719773,-2.082207)
}
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](10.215587,-0.5097931)(10.215587,-1.1097931)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](9.515586,-0.3097931)(10.915586,-0.7097931)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](10.9155855,0.0902069)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](10.915586,-0.109793104)(10.915586,-0.7097931)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](10.446621,0.2177931)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](10.446621,0.017793104)(10.446621,-0.5822069)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](9.515586,0.4902069)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](9.515586,0.2902069)(9.515586,-0.3097931)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](9.939724,0.3350345)(0.2,0.2)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](9.939724,0.1626207)(9.939724,-0.4373793)
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](13.208919,-2.505561)(0.19668874,0.09733542)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](13.012229,-2.5089176)(12.8811035,-3.1869092)(12.8811035,-3.1869092)(12.8811035,-3.1869092)(12.8811035,-3.1869092)(12.8811035,-3.1869092)(12.8811035,-3.1869092)(12.8811035,-3.1869092)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](13.396564,-2.5089176)(13.536733,-3.1869092)
\pscustom[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(12.8811035,-3.1690083)
\lineto(12.954255,-3.2217517)
\curveto(12.990832,-3.248124)(13.137138,-3.2692213)(13.246868,-3.2639465)
\curveto(13.356597,-3.2586718)(13.484614,-3.2323005)(13.539478,-3.1690083)
}
\psellipse[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](13.208919,-2.018884)(0.13112582,0.12978056)
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](13.208918,-2.1486645)(13.208918,-2.5380063)
\rput[bl](9.992,-2.608){BS}
\rput[bl](12.968,-3.6){ED}
\rput(12.824,-0.528){LU}
\rput[bl](4.096,-3.96){Phase 1 : Uplink transmission}
\rput[bl](9.552,-3.912){Phase 2 : Donwlink transmission}
\end{pspicture}
}
```

Comment: Potentially related: [Cisco Icons for network diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22837/cisco-icons-for-network-diagrams)

Comment: Thanks @Jake. I've already seen that page, it is a quite interesting one, but I did not find anything related to **wireless**.

Comment: that are only two different symbols, one additionally with waves. Do you need more symbols?

Comment: @Herbert : I am trying to reproduce the image in Fig.2 : [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.07154.pdf)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228595/adding-arguments-to-a-piece-of-tikzset-code, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153948/is-there-a-tikz-library-for-communications-block, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/telecommunications-symbols, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229548/adding-legends-to-a-tikz-picture-made-of-graphic-components etc.