# how to connect these antennas wirelesslly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, node-connections

I know the qustion in little strange, but i need to connect between these three antennas by wireless channel (with distance d as a name) and  (what is the possible options)
also whats is the possible options for antennas or nodes (another shape in latex). so i can put it in the paper 
and thanks
[image: qus]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzset{block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle,
              minimum height=3em, minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate},
    output/.style = {coordinate},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,t,black}}
    radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment   length=4pt}}}

}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node[block](tx){Base Station};
\node[antenna] at (tx.east) {};
\node[block,below  = 2cm of tx](ttx){GSM900 Tower};
\node[antenna] at (ttx.east) {};
\node[block,right = 5cm of tx](rx){Sensor Node};
\node[antenna,xscale=-1] at (rx.west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: is saw this code in this website but i changed it

Comment: You should provide a link to the original. If the link is wireless, surely not drawing anything at all is the most appropriate option?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228595/adding-arguments-to-a-piece-of-tikzset-code, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153948/is-there-a-tikz-library-for-communications-block, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/telecommunications-symbols, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229548/adding-legends-to-a-tikz-picture-made-of-graphic-components.

Comment: You can do the lines pretty easily (if you want them straight): `\draw (1.5,-1.2) -- (6,2.07);
\draw (1.2, 2.07) -- (6, 2.07);` I think.

Comment: Instead of straight lines, if I may suggest expanding arcs, like `) ) )`.

Comment: You have a defined `radiation` style in your document - why not use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,quotes}% added "calc" and "quotes"
\tikzset{%
    block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate},
   output/.style = {coordinate},
 pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,t,black}}
radiation/.style = {{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment   length=4pt}}},
   zigzag/.style = {% added for solution
    to path={ -- ($(\tikztostart)!.55!-9:(\tikztotarget)$) --
                 ($(\tikztostart)!.45!+9:(\tikztotarget)$) -- (\tikztotarget)
             \tikztonodes},sharp corners}
        }

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node[block](tx){Base Station};
\node[antenna] (ant1) at (tx.east) {};
\node[block,below  = 2cm of tx](ttx){GSM900 Tower};
\node[antenna] (ant2) at (ttx.east) {};
\node[block,right = 5cm of tx](rx){Sensor Node};
\node[antenna,xscale=-1] (ant3) at (rx.west) {};
% added as solution
\coordinate (A1) at ($(ant1)+(0.5,2)$);
\coordinate (A2) at ($(ant2)+(0.5,2)$);
\coordinate (A3) at ($(ant3)+(-0.5,2)$);
\draw[draw=red,very thick,shorten >=1mm,->] (A1) to [zigzag,"$d$"] (A3);
\draw[draw=red,very thick,shorten >=1mm,->] (A2) to [zigzag,"$d$"] (A3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Red alert by lightning?

Comment: urgent message to sensor ....  :-)

Answer (score 8):

Another `wireless` option

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle,
              minimum height=3em, minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate},
    output/.style = {coordinate},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,t,black}},
    radiation/.style={decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=12,segment length=4pt}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node[block](tx){Base Station};
\node[antenna] at (tx.east) {};
\node[block,below  = 2cm of tx](ttx){GSM900 Tower};
\node[antenna] at (ttx.east) {};
\node[block,right = 5cm of tx](rx){Sensor Node};
\node[antenna,xscale=-1] at (rx.west) {};

\draw[radiation] ([shift={(1cm,2cm)}]tx.east)-- node [above=5mm] {d} ([shift={(-1cm,2cm)}]rx.west);

\draw[radiation] ([shift={(1cm,2cm)}]ttx.east)--node [below right=8mm] {d}([shift={(-1cm,2cm)}]rx.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```